# How to create 4 fix blocks in my page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to create 4 blocks in my page to show different information.

Ideally, i would like to have this result :

[image]

What is the best way for creating and positioning theses blocks ?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix blocks"? Do you want to give them a fixed position?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: What desai means is, give us all your code and preferably put it into http://www.jsfiddle.com to demonstrate for us

Comment: You could use a table. understand how to use colspan and widths and you are set.

Comment: The question is unclear, but i have developed a dashboard similar to the posted image using Twitter Bootstrap. Please go through responsive web design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your boxes are going to have fixed heights, then you could simply float them.

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4 {
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    min-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: teal;
}
.box-1, .box-2 {
    height: 200px;
}
.box-1, .box-3 {
    width: 60%;
}
.box-2, .box-4 {
    width: 36%;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/U5X3E/

Comment: How can i do if i want to add another column on the right of the 4 blocs ?

Comment: It depends on your requirements for that column. Here's one way of doing it (if the content of this 5th box become longer that the height of the container, it will get a scrollbar): http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/U5X3E/3/

Comment: Yes, the content of this column will be a list which can be scrollable. But with this new code, it's not centered into the page whereas with the previous code, it was centered..

Answer (score 0):

In a case if you want to have blocks of different heights, you may bind all the blocks in right hand side to a div and the blocks in left hand side in a div. give widths to the wrapper div and float them left.

```
<div class="rhs wrap">
    <div>....</div>
    <div>....</div>
</div>
<div class="lhs wrap">
    <div>....</div>
    <div>....</div>
</div>
```

and the css
`.wrap{
width:50%;
float:left;
}`